# Second monitor is not working on boot

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, mate, ubuntu-mate, external-monitor

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed with ubuntu-mate-desktop.

I work with a second monitor, connected via hdmi.
When I turned-off and then reboot my system, this monitor is black (and cursor does not pass into it), also it is in ON mode:

[image]

I need to turn it off, apply, then turn it on again.

It is annoying and does not have any sense.
How can I fix it?

Comment: It may depend on BIOS/UEFI settings. On my old Lenovo with Intel iGPU I have Config → Display → Boot Display Device set to HDMI, it detects external display first to show boot logo and so on, then login greeter get shown on both screens. One of my laptops - Asustek UX32A with Intel iGPU suffers from [kernel lock-up](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1887916) with HDMI display connected, I think this is not your case. Which hardware do you use? With which kernel drivers? Please add output of `uname -a`, `lshw -C video`, `sudo dmidecode -t system`.